# I'm used for mass

Tags: riddle, word

You might use me for mass
I could tell you your mass
I might even attack you
I sound like a cross

What am I?

HINT1:

> mass in the first line doesn't mean the same as mass in the second line

HINT2:

> Andrew knows about the cross.

HINT3: - each line hints to the solution of the same numbered line in the question

> Songs from a king
>  Maker of the thing
>  The team breaching
>  The land of the fling

Comment: There's a game called "Kirby - Mass Attack"

Comment: I've had a few thoughts but "I sound like a cross" is really throwing me off

Comment: SPOILER / QUESTION:
[St. Andrew?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saltire)

Comment: Yes.  That is correct.

Comment: Are you demo-crossy?

Comment: Is it mass as in 'church mass'?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer seems to be

> (P)salter

You might use me for mass

> Psalter, the book of Psalms might be used in Catholic Mass

I could tell you your mass

> Salter, the manufacturer of weighing scales

I might even attack you

> The word "Assault", or maybe SALT (Supporting Arms Liaison Team), but that seems a little obscure.

I sound like a cross

> A Saltire, also known as St. Andrew's cross

Comment: I'm guessing this is right!  The "attack" bit could be the *person* who does the act, which would get the -er on the end and perhaps fit a little more closely with the others.

Comment: yes, assaulter. I did think of changing it to 'I am the one who attacks you' but didn't, The answer to all of them could be 'A (P)salter' Well done.

Answer (score 8):

I'm going with

> Censer

You might use me for mass

> [Censers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Censer) are used in Catholic mass.

I could tell you your mass

> A **[sensor](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/sensor)** could detect a person's mass.

I might even attack you

> To **[censure](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/censure)** is to "criticize or reproach in a harsh or vehement manner."

I sound like a cross

> To **[censor](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/censor)** is to "to delete (a word or passage of text)," or a feelinferrety pointed out, could be to *cross out*.

Comment: I like it. :)  May I suggest "censure" as in "disapproval" as in maybe something has been crossed out?

Comment: @feelinferrety added that, thanks.  But, after reading the [definition for censure](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/censure) it might even be more appropriate for #3 (attacking), since it mentions "in a harsh or vehement manner."

Comment: Good point. Perhaps the two work out in opposite positions?  As censoring is the act of blocking out (or removing) bits of text/media.

Comment: I like this one. Not what I had in mind, but maybe even better!

Comment: It's pretty cool that there is a "wrong" answer that works this well.

Answer (score 5):

My guess:

> Heart

You might use me for mass

> Mass, as in Catholic mass. If you have attended mass you may be aware that you should be "pure of heart" if you are intending to take communion. So perhaps you do use your heart for mass.

I could tell you your mass

> Your mass, or how much you weigh, could definitely affect the way your heart performs. So your heart could tell you that your mass is too high, leading to:

I might even attack you

> Heart attack!

I sound like a cross

> In Spanish, heart is "corazón", and cross is "cruz". Both words have a similar sound and share some letters.

Comment: This is the first answer to address each line in a thought out manner and it actually makes sense!

Comment: I tell you your exact mass, not just 'too high'

Answer (score 4):

The answer could be

> Scale

You might use me for mass

I could tell you your mass

> We use the scale for weighting.

I might even attack you

> Scale is a symbol of court and justice. If you commit a crime, they might punish you.

I sound like a cross

> [image]

Comment: closest so far but not quite

Comment: I'm more interested in the manufacturer...

Answer (score 1):

Are you

> plus?

You might use me for mass

> refering to voltage plus (positive)

I could tell you your mass

> when you gained weight?

I might even attack you

> not sure about this one

I sound like a cross

> a plus symbol is a cross and maybe it kinda sounds the same in a weird accent?

Answer (score 1):

> Kilo

You might use me for mass
I could tell you your mass

> Kilo is a measurement of mass

I might even attack you

> Kilo-class submarine

I sound like a cross

> Not sure. Maybe they both start with a 'k' sound?

Answer (score 1):

I think

> treadmills

You might use me for mass

I could tell you your mass

> If you use a treadmills often It tells you your mass.

I might even attack you

> If You don't know how to use a treadmills or You use it too much time without be trained You can feel mad.

I sound like a cross

> You can go across treadmills.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is:

> Cruiser

You might use me for mass

> Dunno. My english is too bad

I could tell you your mass

> Cruiserweight (< 200 lb/ 90.7 kg/ 14 st 4)

I might even attack you

> Cruiser (ship)

I sound like a cross

> Cruiser <=> cruz (Spanish)

Answer (score 1):

You might use me for mass

> Hint: Songs from a king
>  => Psalter, pronounced "salter", another name for the book of Psalms (previous attempt: <s>Song of Solomon (book of the Bible, King Solomon) or Psalms (Bible book of King David’s songs)</s>)

I could tell you your mass

> Hint: Maker of the thing
>  => Salter (previous attempt: <s>Detecto? Healthometer? (well-known makers of physician’s scales) Salter and Seca start with S like the other answers but are not as well-known in my area</s>)

I might even attack you

> Hint: The team breaching
>  => Assaulter* (previous attempt: <s>SWAT (swat is to hit; SWAT team breaches entries)</s>) * or there's this SWAT guy named [Jason Salter](https://www.linkedin.com/in/jason-salter-31a6b224)

I sound like a cross

> Hint: The land of the fling
>  => Saltire, the cross in the flag of Scotland (previous attempt: <s>(land of the St. Andrew’s Cross and the Highland Fling) or Saltire, the name for the cross</s>)

What am I?

> A psalter, a salter, assaulter, a saltire (previous attempt: <s>I have no idea. Psalms Salter SWAT Saltire doesn’t get me anywhere but the letter S.</s>)

Comment: So close... good job

Comment: @DavidGlickman: I thought about it a little more... I'm sure of the final, not so sure of #3

Answer (score 0):

The answer is

> human body weight machine

You might use me for mass

> We use a weight scale to measure our total mass

I sound like a cross

> If out of capacity, then it produces a sound.